# Convert list of tuples with dicts to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, tuples

I have a list with tuples that contain dicts which I would like to parse to a pandas dataframe.

```
[
 (
  {'resource': 'Observation1', 'date': '2021-06-01 11:39:00', 'code': '15848'}, 
  {'date': '2021-04-14 00:00:00','resource': 'Observation2'}
 ),
 (
  {'resource': 'Observation1', 'date': '2011-04-01 11:39:00', 'code': '15848'}, 
  {'date': '2012-06-15 00:00:00','resource': 'Observation2'}
 ),
]
```

The resulting dataframe would look as follows:

```
x_resource      x_date                x_code   y_date                y_resource       
Observation 1   2021-06-01 11:39:00   15848    2021-04-14 00:00:00   Observation 2
Observation 1   2011-04-01 11:39:00   15848    2012-06-15 00:00:00   Observation 2
```

I have tried to use the pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples but it can't handle the dicts within the tuples...

Any suggestion on how to solve this?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([x[0] for x in l]).add_prefix('x_').join(pd.DataFrame([x[1] for x in l]).add_prefix('y_'))` ...?

Answer (score 0):

For me this code is working fine. I think it would be helpful for you to solve the problem.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    (
        {'resource': 'Observation1', 'date': '2021-06-01 11:39:00', 'code': '15848'},
        {'date': '2021-04-14 00:00:00', 'resource': 'Observation2'}
    ),
    (
        {'resource': 'Observation1', 'date': '2011-04-01 11:39:00', 'code': '15848'},
        {'date': '2012-06-15 00:00:00', 'resource': 'Observation2'}
    ),
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x', 'y'])
df = pd.concat([df['x'].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('x_'), df['y'].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('y_')], axis=1)

print(df)
```